# Why can't I use standard controls in my .xaml?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, maui

I am trying to create a custom control for my MAUI project and followed this example: https://www.mfractor.com/blogs/news/custom-controls-in-xamarin-forms

But when I use the given xaml it isn't valid:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                x:Class="MyProject.Controls.MyActivityIndicator"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                x:Name="this">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label x:Name="LoadingLabel" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="ActivityIndicator" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</Grid>
```

And I get the error message:

> The type 'Grid' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Visual Studio suggested to add the maui namespace:

```xml
xmlns:maui="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui/design"
```

Then it will recognize all used controls but I cannot use the Grid.Row property after that:

> The attachable property 'Row' was not found in type 'Grid'.

Comment: you are mixing Xamarin Forms and MAUI namespaces

Comment: please do not post errors as images

Comment: @Jason thanks for the quick reply. I have added the error messages as text now as well. 

I have changed the namespace now to MAUI and it recognizes the controls now. Thank you.
But now the error "The attachable property 'Row' was not found in type 'Grid'." still remains.

Comment: try creating a new MAUI `ContentPage` and see what default namespaces it includes

Comment: I already did this after you explained that the namespaces are mixed.
But you gave me a good hint with the ContentPage and I have found a solution. It seems I cannot use Grid as root element. I enclosed the grid with a ContentView control and now it works.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **two** problems within your code:

1. Wrong namespaces (you already fixed that)
2. Missed to fix the inherited class in code behind

Here is the complete code for the custom control and there is no problem to have `Grid` as the root element

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Grid
  x:Class="MauiApp2.Controls.MyActivityIndicator"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.Controls"
  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
  RowDefinitions="*,*">
  <Label
    Grid.Row="0"
    FontAttributes="Bold"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    Text="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyActivityIndicator}}, Path=Text, Mode=OneWay}" />
  <ActivityIndicator
    Grid.Row="1"
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    IsRunning="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MyActivityIndicator}}, Path=IsRunning, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Grid>
```

```cs
namespace MauiApp2.Controls;

public partial class MyActivityIndicator : Grid // <-- you have to change that manually
{
    public MyActivityIndicator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create( nameof( Text ), typeof( string ), typeof( MyActivityIndicator ), default( string ), BindingMode.OneWay );
    public string Text { get => (string)GetValue( TextProperty ); set => SetValue( TextProperty, value ); }

    public static BindableProperty IsRunningProperty = BindableProperty.Create( nameof( IsRunning ), typeof( bool ), typeof( MyActivityIndicator ), false, BindingMode.OneWay );
    public bool IsRunning { get => (bool)GetValue( IsRunningProperty ); set => SetValue( IsRunningProperty, value ); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To root cause for the error message were mixed namespaces from maui and xamarin in the xaml.

After cleaning up the namespaces to only contain maui namespaces the controls were recognized.

But the error "The attachable property 'Row' was not found in type 'Grid'." remained.
It seems you cannot use Grid as root element. After enclosing the grid in a ContentView control everything worked.

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyProject.Controls.MyActivityIndicator">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label x:Name="LoadingLabel" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="ActivityIndicator" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
</Grid>
```